# My Avatar Changed. I didn't change it

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

My avatar on StackOverflow went away, and I now have a generic emblem.

Same thing for Meta

The two avatars were quite neutral, one was my hand on a computer keyboard, the other was a picture of bright yellow Autumn leaves on a tree. I seriously doubt that their content was a factor in the action.

I didn't change either.

What happened ?

Why did it haappen ?

How did it happen ?

What did I do to make this happen ?

What can I do to stop this in the future ?

I hope this is not a duplicate question. I did look at the top five similar questions, and didn't see this one exactly corresponding to any of them.

Comment: Did you have multiple accounts that got merged?

Comment: @psubsee2003  To my knowledge, no, nothing changed.

Comment: Your history says you switched to Gravatar from an uploaded image on August 21, 2013.

Comment: @animuson, huh ? what ? Somebody is lying.  I hope it isn't me !

Comment: @User.1 Do you have a Gravatar account and use it? (I don't know how anyone would be _lying_ here, that's your account history and a thing you did, and unless animuson's version of fun is telling people about account actions they never did, which I doubt, I don't think there's _room_ for lying to be a thing here)

Comment: Perhaps someone (either you or a moderator) did something accidently by misclicking and never realised. I'd just change it back and not worry unless it happens again

Comment: Did you at any point copy your profile from another site around August last year?

Comment: Gravator is the default, so its not that difficult to switch to

Comment: @RichardTingle You bring me the voice of common sense. Thanks. For the moment, your advice will be taken.  Perhaps some kind user who is more on-the-ins than I am will note this for the powers that be. Thanks again for a good idea.

Comment: It wil certainly be taken note of, if more users report it happening it may be a bug. But only time will tell

Comment: @animuson  around August of last year I was increasing my activity on StackExchange, then that dramatically decreased in October (all work related).  What's your thinking ?

Comment: Well if you had an account somewhere that used Gravatar and you chose to save and copy your profile to all sites, that could explain why it changed here. Honestly, I can't tell you much. There's just a random history event that says you switched. There's no other events of modified information around that one, so I can't really even guess at what might have caused it.

Comment: @animuson  How did you get that datum ?  I looked at my profile and didn't see it.

Comment: It's a moderator-only tool that gives us a basic timeline of various events that occur on your account.

Comment: @animuson thanks gotcha

Comment: Thanks to one and all. I'm going home and going to sleep